# When running a working-script in RamDebugger, it refuses to "load" some dll?

Tags: tcl, activetcl

My script (`MyScript.tcl`) includes this line:

```
load MyTclBridge.dll
```

And when I run it this way:

```
tclsh MyScript.tcl
```

It runs ok, but when I use `RamDebugger` to run `MyScript.tcl`, it stops with this error:

```
couldn't load library "MyTclBridge.dll": 
this library or a dependent library could not be found in library path
    while executing
"load MyTclBridge.dll"
    ("after" script)
```

`MyTclBridge.dll` is located in `C:\Windows\System32`. How can I run my script with the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

With problems like this I usually start with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) as this will show you which other Dlls MyTclBridge relies on.  You can then use the [env](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/tclvars.htm#M4) variable that Tcl maintains to show you what the actual PATH that your script has when running under RamDebugger - so check that MyTclBridge and all of it's dependancies are on the PATH.